# Polymer 3 animation not working for shadow dom elements

Tags: animation, polymer, shadow-dom, polymer-3.x

I'm attempting to update the Polymer 2 grain-masonry project to use Polymer 3 and I'm 90% there, but I cannot get the animation for adding new elements to work correctly. The artifacts are added through the shadow dom and it seems that even though the class name is added, the animation doesnt work.

I've tried changing how the keyframes are added to the javascript file as well as putting the animate classes on the ":host" as opposed to ":host ::slotted"

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

        <title>masonry-layout demo</title>

        <script src="../node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

        <script type="module">
            import '@polymer/iron-demo-helpers/demo-pages-shared-styles';
            import '@polymer/iron-demo-helpers/demo-snippet';
        </script>
        <script>
        function addBelow() {
            let newArticle = document.createElement('article');
            newArticle.innerHTML = 'added below';
            document.getElementById('masonry').appendChild(newArticle);
        }
        function addAbove() {
            let newArticle = document.createElement('article');
            let masonry = document.getElementById('masonry');
            newArticle.innerHTML = 'added above';
            document.getElementById('masonry').prependChild(newArticle);
        }
    </script>
        <script type="module" src="../masonry-layout.js"></script>

    <custom-style>
        <style is="custom-style" include="demo-pages-shared-styles">
        </style>
        <style>
        article {
            background: #36abcc;
            width: 29%;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 2%;
            color: #fff;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        grain-masonry {
            background: #ccc;
        }
    </style>
    </custom-style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="vertical-section-container centered">
        <h3>Basic masonry-layout demo</h3>
        <button onclick="addBelow();">add below</button>
    <button onclick="addAbove();">add above</button>
        <demo-snippet>
            <template>
                <masonry-layout id="masonry">
                    <article>
                        Power
                    </article>
                    <article style="height: 100px;">
                        To
                    </article>
                    <article style="height: 190px;">
                        The
                    </article>
                    <article style="height: 310px;">
                        People
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        Power
                    </article>
                    <article style="height: 140px;">
                        To
                    </article>
                    <article style="height: 210px;">
                        The
                    </article>
                    <article style="height: 230px;">
                        People
                    </article>
                </masonry-layout>
            </template>
        </demo-snippet>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**masonry-layout.js**

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import {afterNextRender} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/render-status.js';
import { FlattenedNodesObserver } from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/flattened-nodes-observer.js';
import './masonry.pkgd.min.js';
/**
 * `masonry-layout`
 * Polymer 3 wrapper for masonry javascript library
 *
 * @customElement
 * @polymer
 * @demo demo/index.html
 */
class MasonryLayout extends PolymerElement {

    static get is() {
        return 'masonry-layout'
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            itemSelector: {
                type: String,
                reflectToAttribute: true,
                value: 'article'
            },
            transitionDuration: {
                type: Number,
                reflectToAttribute: true,
                value: 0
            }
        };
    }

    static get template() {
        return html`
      <style>

        @keyframes containerMasonryMoveToOrigin {
        from {
                    opacity: 0;
                }
        to { transform: translateY(0); opacity: 1; }
    }

        :host {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
        }

        :host .masonry-layout-animate-move-up) {
                        transform: translateY(200px);
                        opacity: 0;
                        animation: containerMasonryMoveToOrigin 5s ease forwards;
                    }
        .masonry-layout-animate-move-down) {
                        transform: translateY(-200px);
                        opacity: 0;
                        animation: containerMasonryMoveToOrigin 0.65s ease forwards;
                    }

      </style>

      <slot id="slot"></slot>

    `;
    }

    init() {
        this.raw = new Masonry(this, {
            itemSelector: this.itemSelector,
            transitionDuration: this.transitionDuration,
            initLayout: false
        });
        afterNextRender(this, function () {
            this.layout();
        });
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        this.init();
        this._loadObserver = function (event) {
            let target = event.target;
            if (target.tagName === 'IMG') {
                this.layout();
            }
        }.bind(this);
        this.addEventListener('load', this._loadObserver, true);
        this.toggleSlotObsever = false;
        this._slotObserver = new FlattenedNodesObserver(this.$.slot, (info) => {
            if (this.toggleSlotObsever) {
                let addedElements = info.addedNodes.filter((node) => {
                    return (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.nodeName === this.itemSelector.toUpperCase())
                });
                let removedElements = info.removedNodes.filter((node) => {
                    return (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.nodeName === this.itemSelector.toUpperCase())
                });
                if (addedElements.length > 0 || removedElements.length > 0) {
                    this.reInit();
                }
            }
            this.toggleSlotObsever = true;
        });
    }
    disconnectedCallback() {
        this._slotObserver.disconnect();
        this.removeEventListener('load', this._loadObserver);
    }
    layout() {
        this.raw.layout();
    }
    reInit() {
        this.raw.destroy();
        this.init();
    }
    appendChild(element) {
        this.toggleSlotObsever = false;
        element.classList.add('masonry-layout-animate-move-up');
        element.addEventListener('animationend', function (event) {
            //event.target.classList.remove('masonry-layout-animate-move-up');
        });
        super.appendChild(element);
        this.raw.addItems(element);
        afterNextRender(this, function () {
            this.layout();
            this.toggleSlotObsever = true;
        });
    }
    appendChildren(elements) {
        for (let element of elements) {
            this.appendChild(element);
        }
    }
    prependChild(element) {
        this.insertBefore(element, this.children[0]);
    }
    prependChildren(elements) {
        for (let element of elements) {
            this.prependChild(element);
        }
    }
    insertBefore(element, before) {
        if (element.nodeName === '#document-fragment') {
            element = element.querySelector(this.itemSelector);
        }
        this.toggleSlotObsever = false;
        element.classList.add('masonry-layout-animate-move-down');
        element.addEventListener('animationend', function (event) {
            //event.target.classList.remove('masonry-layout-animate-move-down');
        });
        super.insertBefore(element, before);
        this.raw.prepended(element);
        afterNextRender(this, function () {
            this.layout();
            this.toggleSlotObsever = true;
        });
    }
}

window.customElements.define('masonry-layout', MasonryLayout);
```

Comment: If I add the keyframes and the class css to a <style> element in under the <head> tag the animation works appropriately...seems like this is related to slotted elements in Polymer 3?

Comment: The above comment is a bit wrong. The class in the template for slotted components works if I use ":host ::slotted (.masonry-layout-animate-move-up)..."

However the keyframes still has to be added to the head <style> element...leaving it in the template still causes problems